# PHP intval not acting as expected

Tags: php, int, type-conversion, php-7

I'm issuing a strange behavior with intval in PHP 7.0

It seems like using `intval` after a floating number computation returns wrong values.

Here's an example:

```
echo intval(920); // This prints 920 as expected
echo intval(9.2 * 100); // this prints 919!!!
```

Probably I'm misunderstanding the correct usage of `intval`.

Can someone explain me why this happens?

Comment: refer to [php float issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/6521116)

Comment: This is because 9.2 is converted to a float. The float could have a value of 9.199999999999999999 which is lower than 9.2 because of limited precision. The integer part of 919.9999999999999 is 919.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try this:

```
(int)(9.2 * 10)
```

OR

See the example below, this is from a comment in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
$n="19.99";
print intval($n*100); // prints 1998
print intval(strval($n*100)); // prints 1999
```

Comment: Same issue... `echo((int)(9.2 * 100));` gives 9.19 :(

Comment: Let me know if the second solution doesn't work for you.